# DynamoDB Mapper mapping Collection Datatypes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to map by custom defined class to a DynamoDB table using DynamoDB Mapper annotations:

```
public class MyClass {
  String string1;
  List<String> stringList;
  Boolean flag;
  Map<String, String> map;
}
```

I know DDB mapper supports limited data type. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html

But how can I map this class ? Any help on how can I map the list and map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DynamoDB mapper will automatically interpret and assign the correct DynamoDB 
data type based on the Java type.

If you want to assign the DDB data type specifically, you can use [DynamoDBTyped](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTyped.html) annotation.

Please refer the boolean attribute in the below example.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.DynamoDBAttributeType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTyped;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "yourTableName")
public class MyClass {

    String string1;
    List<String> stringList;
    Boolean flag;
    Map<String, String> map;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "string1")
    public String getString1() {
        return string1;
    }

    public void setString1(String string1) {
        this.string1 = string1;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "stringList")
    public List<String> getStringList() {
        return stringList;
    }

    public void setStringList(List<String> stringList) {
        this.stringList = stringList;
    }

    @DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBAttributeType.BOOL)
    public Boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(Boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "map")
    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey @notionquest thanks a lot! Just had figured this out.. But special thanks for DynamoDBTyped. Can you please also (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656642/dynamodb-mapper-hashkey-on-non-member) look at this.. thanks in advance !!

Comment: Sure, could you please accept the answer if it was helpful?

Comment: @notionquest and how to mark types of map? for example i have a map with `Map<String,Boolean>` for now dynamoDb stores it as `Map<String,Int>` (it stores bools values as 1 or 0).