# DynamoDB Mapper HashKey on non member

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Just wanted to confirm if this is possible. I tried this in my code.

```
public class MyClass {
    String a ;
    String b;
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "a_b")
    public String getHashKey() {
       return a+"_"+b;
    }
}
```

It throws the following error :

```
could not invoke null on class <classname> with value <ab> of type class java.lang.String
```

How I am using it is like :
Firstly I inserted a record in dynamodb using `mapper.save()` with hashkey="ab", now when I am doing `mapper.load(Clazz.class, "ab", rangeKey)` , I get this error.

Comment: i think u are getting exception cause `a and b` are null , try to initialize them before using them.

Comment: here "ab" was the  value. ( String a = "a" ; String = "b")

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Hey! So what I did was create a new attribute "a_b" and set its value while inserting in db.